# Git pull/push/clone (also github for mac login) stopped working

Tags: git, macos, github-for-mac

I'm trying 'clone', 'pull', 'push' - it's not working.

It was working 3 days ago, during this time I've installed (only) slack client and minecraft (with Apple java of some sort).

System is MacOSX, git is version 2.5.0 (installed with homebrew), openssl is 0.9.8zf 19 Mar 2015 (also homebrew).

git pull and git push just 'freezes', git clone freezes after showing 'Cloning into '...'' message.

It's system - wide (tried make new mac user and clone from it's account) and it happens on every remote git repo (github, gitlab, company's repo).

The same repos (with the same credentials(id_rsa)) works fine on my second (windows8.1) computer.

Another disturbing thing that may help solve this problem:
After this happened I've installed github for macosx, when I'm trying to login to my github account (using user/passwd) the spinning circle takes forever. (It's different behaviour than bad user/passwd that gives normal error message).

Comment: Post the output of using the `-v` (verbose) flag.

Comment: Tried. Output is empty also with -v flag.

Comment: What does `which git` display?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/git`

Comment: What does the homebrew `git` give you over the Xcode command-line-tools `git`?

Comment: I (and my workplace admin) like to have our tools updated. Which version is command-line-tools git?

Comment: I don't know, but likely much earlier than 2.5.0.